# Javascript anchor to same page not working

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

So I have a webpage where instead of using a new html document (It's for phones so loading a new html page each time makes it really slow) for each page I have sections which represents the different pages.

It looks like this:

```
<body>

    <!-- each body must contain att least one section that is shown as a page -->
    <section id = "page-1" data-ff-role = "home default swipe-in">

        <!-- each section should have a header -->
        <header style="background-color: #CCE4F5;">
```

So each section I create has it's own id. Now when i try to link to it using:

```
     function callback_listAllPOI(xmlObj){ 
        console.log("callback_listAllPOI");

        var names = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("POI_namn");
        var comments = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("POI_kommentar");
        for (i=0;i<names.length; i++){
            var text = '<li><a href="#page-1">' + names[i].textContent + ': ' + comments[i].textContent + '</a></li>';
            $("#deployPOIList").append(text);
        }

    };
```

I can add 'li' items to the targeted 'ol' and add the text and everything but the href doesn't work. When it is pressed it just adds #page-1 at the end of my url instead of just going to the anchor on the page. I've tried creating an a tag with document.createElement('a') but it gives the same result.

**Edit**: I can create a link tag statically to the webpage where the anchor works, it's only the anchor with javascript that doesn't work. 
This one works just like it should:

```
<li><a href="#page-1">Page 1</a></li>
```

**Edit 2:** Tried both but didn't make a difference for me. Since I had to be done with it yesterday to be on schedule I had to make a decision so I changed to PhP and got it working that way. Thanks for your answers though and hopefully they will help someone with a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Maybe you do not have much content on your webpage such that the browser would not scroll to the appropriate position. I have an example here in the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/z78p7d5L/8/

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="deployPOIList"></ul>    

<section id = "page-1" data-ff-role = "home default swipe-in">

        <!-- each section should have a header -->
        <header style="background-color: #CCE4F5;">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
        </header>
    </section>

<section id = "page-2" data-ff-role = "home default swipe-in">

        <!-- each section should have a header -->
        <header style="background-color: #CCE4F5;">testtest test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
        </header>
    </section>
```

JS Code:

```
var text1 = '<li><a href="#page-1">hello1</a></li>';
    var text2 = '<li><a href="#page-2">hello2</a></li>';
            $("#deployPOIList").append(text1).append(text2);
```

Comment: Each section only contains a few lines of text and an audio tag and/or a picture, so might be that i don't have enough content. Will try to add more and see if that works! thx @ArinCool

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to mimic [JQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-multi-page/). In your case you might have been displaying one page at a time and hiding others with the help of css.
However changing the hash of URL(through anchor click) can not display the hidden elements. It will just try to scroll to that id if that is not hidden.
What you can do is, to attach an onclick handler and first set the visibility on and then scroll. Something like below

```
$(document).on('click', 'anchorSelector', handlePageNavigation);
function handlePageNavigation() {
    var $obj = $(this);
    //get Page Id by inspecting $obj href property
    //use some class to mark active / inactive pages
    //remove the active class with all page section
    //add active class to current page so that its display = block      
}
```